# Member of a .NET class is empty in the VB6 object browser

Tags: vb.net, com, vb6, com-interop

At the moment I´m trying tests on the interoperability of VB6 and .NET using COM. 
I have followed this simple example to call a .NET component from COM.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973802.aspx
The DLL is registered and the assembly was "succesfully added to the cache". However when I take a look into the object browser of VB6 I can only see methods of the interface and not of the actual class. COM is set on visible and the correct path for the *KeyFile*, are both in the *AssemblyInfo.vb* file.   The .NET Class+Interface looks like this:

```
Public Interface iTemperature
'some properties and functions
End Interface

Public Class NET_Temperature
Implements iTemperature
'some implemented public properties and functions
End Class
```

When I try to run the following Code:

```
     Set moTempClass = New PhysServer2.NET_Temperature
     Set moTemp = moTempClass
```

I´m getting the well known 429-runtime error, saying that creating an object through an Active-X-component does not work. There is a lot of information on the internet regarding this error with unregistered DLL/TLB, but I´m more concerned about the fact that only the methods and properties of the interface are shown in the object browser and not the implemented methods/properties of the interface - the class. How can I fix this Error and make the methods in my class sort of visible to COM and the object browser?

Comment: That is entirely normal, COM code can only every uses an interface and the implementation is completely hidden.  Whatever your real problem might be, this isn't it.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. I'll keep looking for an answer regarding the active-x-component error, at least one thing less to worry about.

Comment: The article you are following is a bit dated and the VB compiler makes creating COM objects very simple via the [ComClassAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.comclassattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You don't need to define an interface as the compiler will generate one for you based on Public Properties/Methods/Events.   I would recommend that you review [Walkthrough: Creating COM Objects with Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x66s8zcd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Even if I follow the walkthrough you suggested, I still get the same error message when trying to instantiate an object (in Visual Basic) from the Visual Studio COM class. There is a note at the end of the walkthrough, saying that the object I generate is not a true COM object and therefore adding a reference results in an error. Also that it cannot be used from other VB applications. I really don´t know how to solve the issue considering that every msdn-article seems to be out dated.

Comment: I solved the issue by removing the strong name from the assembly. Now everything works just fine. Thanks a lot for your help on my first post, no regrets whatsoever creating an account.

Comment: Also make sure that "Register for COM interop" is activated in the project properties -> compile options.